# Pandas dataframe combine two columns to get datetime column

Tags: python, pandas

Given the dataframe below where `uptime` is time in nanoseconds, how to combine columns `date_is` with `uptime` to form a new column of type datetime object.

```
    date_is              uptime     
0   14/05/2016 10:54:33  11537640270059 
1   14/05/2016 10:54:33  11537650128140 
2   14/05/2016 10:54:33  11537659894659 
3   14/05/2016 10:54:33  11537679549779 
4   14/05/2016 10:54:33  11537699204899
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) + [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_is']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['uptime'])
print (df)
               date_is          uptime                           new
0  14/05/2016 10:54:33  11537640270059 2016-05-14 14:06:50.640270059
1  14/05/2016 10:54:33  11537650128140 2016-05-14 14:06:50.650128140
2  14/05/2016 10:54:33  11537659894659 2016-05-14 14:06:50.659894659
3  14/05/2016 10:54:33  11537679549779 2016-05-14 14:06:50.679549779
4  14/05/2016 10:54:33  11537699204899 2016-05-14 14:06:50.699204899
```

Is possible also converted columns assign back:

```
df['date_is'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_is'])
df['uptime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['uptime'])
df['new'] = df['date_is'] + df['uptime']
print (df)
              date_is          uptime                           new
0 2016-05-14 10:54:33 03:12:17.640270 2016-05-14 14:06:50.640270059
1 2016-05-14 10:54:33 03:12:17.650128 2016-05-14 14:06:50.650128140
2 2016-05-14 10:54:33 03:12:17.659894 2016-05-14 14:06:50.659894659
3 2016-05-14 10:54:33 03:12:17.679549 2016-05-14 14:06:50.679549779
4 2016-05-14 10:54:33 03:12:17.699204 2016-05-14 14:06:50.699204899
```

Comment: This worked great! If your 'time' column comes in a different format, you first need to convert them to nanoseconds. Eg. my time column is hours in a military format like: 
0      100
1      200
...
22    2300
23    2400
and I simply multiplied it: 
 pd.to_timedelta(df.Hour*100000*60*60)
Ideally, we would pass the format as a parameter to to_timedelta ...

Comment: @hebeha - You can use `pd.to_timedelta(df.Hour, unit='h')`

Comment: with the military format I get each hour multiplied by 100 if I use unit='h', and to_timedelta doesn't have the string format, it would be '%-I' in this case.

Comment: Another workaround would be 'pd.to_timedelta(data.Hour/100, unit='h')'